# How to check input patterns within a store procedure SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pattern-matching, procedure

I have a store procedure that currently takes 21 parameters.
@Concept_Name,@K1,@W1 .....@Kn, @Wn

Would like to know how i can use a check input pattern to ensure its correctly formatted and the correct data types are used. And prints an error message to the user if the string pattern is invalid (Missing W, K, comma or reversed)

Data type for @Concept_Name is varchar(55)
Data Type for @K is varchar(55)
Data type for @W is decimal (3,2)

can treat as two strings I.E '@Concept_Name' and the other '@K1,@W1.....@Kn,@Wn'

Thanks for the help

Comment: 21 parameters?  Holy cow!  
What are you using for a front end?  You'd be much better off checking it there, I think.

Comment: Yeah its part of an assignment. Where we take the user input of the concept name and the 10 key words and their weights. And the check must be done within the procedure.

Comment: Isn't there a policy against this??? There should be.

Comment: Please explain by policy agaisnt this. thanks